# Open sms automatically using javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I am trying to open sms automatically using javascript. Tried these,

```
<img src="x" onerror="location.href='sms:555?body=smsexampletext'" \>
<iframe src="sms:555?body=smsexampletext"></iframe>
<script>document.location="sms:555?body=smsexampletext";</script>
```

However, these only work on mobile browsers, not on chrome for mobile browsers.
Does anyone know a smarter approach to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code :

Launch android default SMS application

```
 <p><a href="sms:555?body=smsexampletext"> Send Sms  </span></a></p>
```

Comment: Thanks but its not automated.